# What does the subscript mean in $156_{10}$? Why not just write $156$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, integers, binary

I'm learning how to convert decimal to binary, and the site I'm using shows how to convert the decimal number $156_{10}$ to binary, but it really just means the integer $156$. Why do they put $156_{10}$ and not just $156$? What is the $10$ for?

Comment: It means $156$ in base $10$.  $156$ is also a number in base $7$, for example, so it's there to minimize ambiguity.

Comment: When there is more than one base in play, the subscript is to emphasize the base for the digits.

Comment: Use `150_{10}` for $150_{10}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The subscript denotes base. For example, $21_{10}$ means "$21$ in base $10$", whereas in binary (base $2$) you'd write $10101_2$.